# PlayonLinux says i need 32bits OpenGL libs, can someone give me Nvidia 32bit libraries

Tags: opengl, playonlinux

So I am totally new to Ubuntu and saw that someone said that I need to install the 32bit libraries. Can someone tell where do I find them? I know I can get them with sudo apt-get install but I don't know what they are called. Hope this explains and solves the problem.
I am using Ubuntu 12.04 64bit version.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 12.04 64bit version.

Comment: Is there any chance you have nvidia optimus? If so, that makes a huge difference.

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands from terminal

```
apt-get install nvidia-glx
apt-get install nvidia-glx-legacy-96xx
```

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package nvidia-glx is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'nvidia-glx' has no installation candidate

This is what i get. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 64bit version.

Comment: 1.`sudo apt-get install nvidia-glx-ia32`, 2.`apt-get install nvidia-glx-legacy-96xx-ia32`    3.`sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`, try these one after the other

Comment: are you sure that are the package names? it says unable to locate package, for all of them

Comment: since you are using 64-bit version you try installing this `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`, this install will give full compatibility with 32bit applcations,  long back i used the above commands so i may be miss spelled them , for sure they worked for me when i had these issues.

Comment: ok thanks anyway i did learn a little. i installed that a while back.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`

Answer (score -1):

```
wget http://ubuntu.wikimedia.org/ubuntu//pool/main/f/freeglut/freeglut3_2.6.0-1ubuntu2_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i freeglut3_2.6.0-1ubuntu2_i386.deb
```

These commands will install 32 bit version of OpenGL library.

Comment: that was a very good answer but didnt fix the problem on playonlinux, it just keeps saying unable to locate 32bits libraries and after that it can't find cURL whatever that is.

Comment: Can you please post the complete error message which you are getting?

Comment: i will when i get back from college

Comment: Why not just use the package manager? `sudo apt-get install freeglut3:i386`